# Redis Insights - exec format error [raspberry pi, docker-compose]

Tags: docker, redis, raspberry-pi, redisinsights

Trying to run Redis insight inside the docker container. Here is the complete container log:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

it exits immediately after the start.

I'm running this with docker-compose on ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 2b:

```
  redisinsight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight:1.7.0
    container_name: redis_gui
    ports:
      - '80:8001'
    volumes:
      - ./redisinsight:/db
```

Is there anything that can be done without interfering in the docker image [redisinsigt:1.10.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/redislabs/redisinsight/1.10.1/images/sha256-fd4bff16761308521952e802e1ac1fcafb0d78088c508cf3762754aa954c7009?context=explore)  or the actual code? Maybe this is something caused by Pi architecture, I'm wondering

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry PI uses ARM architecture. The container is for x86-64 architecture.